# Layout / tap target size issues in iOS app

Tags: bug, mobile-app

I've noticed since the December update to the iOS app that the inbox and achievement buttons in the toolbar are a bit... iffy.

- they seem to move around a tiny bit based on whether achievements is showing a rep gain or its default icon
- when achievements shows a rep gain, it's much harder to tap

It's as if the frame of the achievements button is changing to the min size fitting it's content instead of staying at 44x44 (or whatever bar buttons are supposed to be these days).

Seen in iOS 10.2 on iPhone 7 Plus.